# In the pgAdmin ERD tool, how do I use a function as the default value for a column?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to create an Account table with pgAdmin's ERD tool. In the default value for the account_id column, I am trying to put in uuid_generate_v4() from the extension.

[image]

But I end up with 'uuid_generate_v4()' in the SQL schema, which doesn't work because it's in quotes:

[image]

Oddly, when I take out the quotes, run the SQL, and then view the table in the ERD editor again, it has uuid_generate_v4() as the default value, which didn't work in the first place to create the table.

Is there anyway to create a table using a function for a default value? Or do you have to remove the quotes from each function every time you want to update the schema using the ERD tool?

Comment: Have you followed the advice in line 2 of the script?

Comment: @Patrick I guess it seemed more probable to me that it is the default behavior of the pgAdmin ERD tool to interpret the text of uuid_generate_v4() as the string 'uuid_generate_v4()' and not a function. I guess I am asking to verify if other people know this is a thing that you have deal with when using PostgreSQL, or if this is unexpected behavior.

Comment: In my installation (PG 11.5, PgAdmin4 6.5) the ERD tool works just fine with the function properly specified without quotes. Do you have the `uuid-ossp` extension loaded on your installation? If you are using PG13+, you can also use the `gen_random_uuid()` function without an extension.